# How to use the same command for different targets?

Tags: makefile

Here is a simple Makefile:

```
all: actual.txt test1.txt test2.txt

actual.txt: header.txt actual_part1.txt actual_part2.txt footer.txt
    cat $^ > $@

test1.txt: header.txt actual_part1.txt test1_part2.txt footer.txt
    cat $^ > $@

test2.txt: header.txt test2_huge_part.txt footer.txt
    cat $^ > $@
```

As you can see, all three targets are built with the same command, repeated three times. Is it possible to somehow reduce the repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the makefile as you've provided it, there are a few ways.

One is to put the recipe into a variable:

```
BLDTXT = cat $^ $@

all: actual.txt test1.txt test2.txt

actual.txt: header.txt actual_part1.txt actual_part2.txt footer.txt
        $(BLDTXT)

test1.txt: header.txt actual_part1.txt test1_part2.txt footer.txt
        $(BLDTXT)

test2.txt: header.txt test2_huge_part.txt footer.txt
        $(BLDTXT)
```

That doesn't reduce the number of lines to write, but it does allow you to make changes to the recipe in one place.

Another option is to create a single rule and move the prerequisite definitions to other lines, like this:

```
BLDTXT = cat $^ $@
ALLTXT = actual.txt test1.txt test2.txt

all: $(ALLTXT)

$(ALLTXT):
        $(BLDTXT)

actual.txt: header.txt actual_part1.txt actual_part2.txt footer.txt
test1.txt: header.txt actual_part1.txt test1_part2.txt footer.txt
test2.txt: header.txt test2_huge_part.txt footer.txt
```

Comment: Huh, didn't know I could have two recipes for a target. Thanks, I guess that pretty much covers it.

Comment: You cannot have two _recipes_ for a target.  But you can have two (or more) _rules_ for a target, as long as only rule has a recipe (the recipe is the script used to update the target).  Some of the tools which automatically generate header file dependencies write a separate rule for every prerequisite.